# HighCharts data from SQL Server, classic asp

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, highcharts

I'm trying to populate a HighCharts dataset with results from SQL Server in Classic ASP, but can't seem to get the syntax down correctly. This is a very basic beginning to my customization, I figure get the datasets rendering and everything is easy from there.

The below loop is working correctly, and is grabbing the data correctly from my sproc. My issue I believe is in the `data[]` section of the actual `var options =` section

```vbs
dim xAxisData()
dim yAxisData()
j = 0               
    adoRsGraph.MoveFirst

if adoRsGraph.EOF = false then

    Do Until adoRsGraph.EOF
        reDim xAxisData(j)
        reDim yAxisData(j)
            xAxisData(j) = adoRsGraph("Value")
            yAxisData(j) = adoRsGraph("Date")

        j = j + 1
        adoRsGraph.MoveNext
    Loop

end if



$(function () { 
        var options = {
        chart:{
            type:'line',
            renderTo: 'chartContainer'               
            },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples','Bananas','Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title:{
                text: 'Assets'          
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Dates',
            data: [<% For Each item In yAxisData    Response.Write(item & ",") Next %>],
            color: '#006600'
        }]
    }
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
});
```

receiving error of;

> ```vbs
> Microsoft VBScript compilation 
> Description:Expected end of statement
> Line:90
> ```

with line 90 being;

```vbs
data: [<% For Each item In yAxisData    Response.Write(item & ",") Next %>],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO I think it would be better to break out the logic that transforms the data into a comma separated list into a function. I also added `preserve` when you redim the arrays. Otherwise you will lose data.

```
dim xAxisData()
dim yAxisData()
j = 0               
    adoRsGraph.MoveFirst

if adoRsGraph.EOF = false then
    Do Until adoRsGraph.EOF
        reDim preserve xAxisData(j)
        reDim preserve yAxisData(j)
        xAxisData(j) = adoRsGraph("Value")
        yAxisData(j) = adoRsGraph("Date")

        j = j + 1
        adoRsGraph.MoveNext
    Loop
end if

$(function () { 
    var options = {
    chart:{
        type:'line',
        renderTo: 'chartContainer'               
        },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples','Bananas','Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title:{
            text: 'Assets'          
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Dates',
        data: [<%= GetYAxisData() %>],
        color: '#006600'
    }]
}
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
});
```

The original code you posted `For Each item In yAxisData Response.Write(item & ",")` would create an extra comma (,) at the end leading to unexpected behaviour. Using Join() function is a better option I think.

```
function GetYAxisData()
    GetYAxisData = Join(yAxisData, ",")
end function
```

Comment: you my friend are a life saver, it's amazing to me how far off my thoughts are in classic asp, just don't do enough of it, these are for redesigns of old code from well before my time.  Thank you very much!